# Python: Find an item in a list

Tags: python, list

So I'm having trouble figuring out how to write this. The part I'm having trouble with is trying to figure out a way to find any match that is less than the max cost, and I can't figure out how to find the itemtype and max cost values in a list in another list.

The question: Find an   item

When the user selects   2   to  find    an  item,   they    should  be  prompted    with    the item    type,   and 
the maximum price they  are willing to  pay for the item.   Your    code    should  then    search  the 
list    and return  the first   item    with    the correct type    and a   cost    that    is  less    than    or  equal   to
the price   that    the user    will    pay.

Use the following   text    in  your    prompts:
"Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c:" <--these are the only options for item type.
"Enter the maximum item cost:"

For example,    if  the user    types   b   and 50, they    want    a   bicycle and are willing to  pay up  to
$50 for it.

Your    program should  find    the first   bicycle in  the list    that    sells   for $50 or  less.
If  a   match   is  found,  print   “Sold for”

Use the following print statement:
print "Sold", itemType, "for", itemCost
where   itemType and    itemCost are    variables   that    store   the type    of  the item    and its cost.

The itemType is one of  the following:  bike,   microwave,  dresser,    truck,  or chicken.

The itemCost is the actual  item    cost,   not what    the user    is  willing to  pay.

The item    should  then    be  removed from    the list.
If  the item    is  not found,  do  nothing.

This is what I have so far:

```
p=2
a=[['b', 40], ['c', 330], ['m', 50], ['d', 70], ['t', 85]]
while p == 2:
    if len(a) > 0:
        itemtype = raw_input("Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c:")
        maxcost = raw_input("Enter the maximum item cost:")
        x = [itemtype, maxcost]
```

Notes: the list a is just a reference while I figure out how to do it. The real a will be changed by the user.
Thanks.

Comment: So you want to figure out if the item type is in a and, if the type is in a, see if the entered maximum is below the integer stored in the list?

Comment: This screams dictionary

Comment: Your best first step is to turn `a` into a dictionary like `{'a': [10, 30, 50], 'b': [22, 23, 82], ...}`.  Your logic is simple after that: 1) see if you have any items left in the value for `type`, and if so 2) check if `dict[type][0]` <= entered amount.

Comment: Actually, what I suggested will not work as I sorted the values and thus changed the original order.  See @PadraicCunningham answer using bisect to use the first matching item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary, storing the items as keys and lists of values, you can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) to efficiently find the closest price to the user:

```
def purchase():
    from bisect import bisect_left
    data = {"b": [10, 20, 30, 40], "c": [100, 200, 330], "m": [20, 40, 50], "d": [70, 80, 90], "t": [50, 85, 100]}
    for _ in range(2):
        item_type = raw_input("Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c:")
        max_cost = int(input("Enter the maximum item cost:"))
        v = data[item_type]
        ind = bisect_left(v, max_cost, hi=len(v) - 1)
        if v[ind] <= max_cost:
            print("Sold for {}".format(v[ind]))
            v.remove(v[ind])
        else:
            print("Sorry, cheapest is {}".format(v[0]))
```

Demo:

```
In [2]: purchase()
Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c:b
Enter the maximum item cost:10
Sold for 10
Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c:b
Enter the maximum item cost:10
Sorry, cheapest is 20
```

bisect will find the price in the list in `O(log n)` time, if the  item at the index returns from bisect is <= we have a sale so we output the message and remove the item, if it is not then the user is cheap and cannot afford our high quality items and we show them the cheapest available.

You lso need to handle the case when a user enters either something not in our shop or something that cannot be cast to an int, a `try/except` and a `while` loop will do that for you, that I will leave as an exercise for yourself.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help.